# Magento mass_action indexes - how do they work?

Tags: magento, indexing, magento-1.9

I have created some code to update prices in Magento.  I have found that updating the product object itself is a bit slow - so i've found this that can update single attributes at a time and it's a lot quicker.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($prod->getId()), array('price',10), $storeId);
```

When i run this, an entry is created in the index_event table -

**type**: mass_action,

**entity**: catalog_product

**new_data**:

a:12:{s:35:"cataloginventory_stock_match_result";b:1;s:41:"Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Indexer_Stock";a:1:{s:35:"cataloginventory_stock_match_result";b:1;}s:34:"catalog_product_price_match_result";b:1;s:40:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price";a:2:{s:34:"catalog_product_price_match_result";b:1;s:25:"reindex_price_product_ids";a:11:{i:0;s:2:"39";i:1;s:3:"363";i:2;s:3:"367";i:3;s:3:"371";i:4;s:3:"375";i:5;s:3:"379";i:6;s:3:"383";i:7;s:3:"387";i:8;s:3:"391";i:9;s:3:"395";i:10;s:3:"399";}}s:24:"catalog_url_match_result";b:0;s:33:"catalog_product_flat_match_result";b:1;s:39:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat";a:3:{s:33:"catalog_product_flat_match_result";b:1;s:33:"catalog_product_flat_force_update";b:1;s:32:"catalog_product_flat_product_ids";a:11:{i:0;s:2:"39";i:1;s:3:"363";i:2;s:3:"367";i:3;s:3:"371";i:4;s:3:"375";i:5;s:3:"379";i:6;s:3:"383";i:7;s:3:"387";i:8;s:3:"391";i:9;s:3:"395";i:10;s:3:"399";}}s:34:"catalog_category_flat_match_result";b:0;s:37:"catalog_category_product_match_result";b:1;s:43:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Product";a:1:{s:37:"catalog_category_product_match_result";b:1;}s:35:"catalogsearch_fulltext_match_result";b:1;s:41:"Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext";a:3:{s:35:"catalogsearch_fulltext_match_result";b:1;s:27:"catalogsearch_force_reindex";b:1;s:25:"catalogsearch_product_ids";a:11:{i:0;s:2:"39";i:1;s:3:"363";i:2;s:3:"367";i:3;s:3:"371";i:4;s:3:"375";i:5;s:3:"379";i:6;s:3:"383";i:7;s:3:"387";i:8;s:3:"391";i:9;s:3:"395";i:10;s:3:"399";}}}

I've found that when i run the code in a loop, this record is added to automatically.

Is there a point where this data is used to reindex only the affected products?

What happens if you have 'manual indexing' enabled?

It's new to me so hopefully someone has some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has an ability to trigger the index event on every product update action. In your case you are trying to update product by bulk action. Hence, magento triggers the full reindexing.

1. You can go with the Magento model instead of action if the number of products is lesser in numbers.
2. Else, to stop the index process, by changing the flag is_visible to false; under the following path Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Price.php. This will restrict the automatic indexing process.

After your script completes. You can do the manual price index.

Comment: Hi Gowtham,  thanks for your answer.  I am updating a lot of products so I don't want to use the product model.  I would like to understand how the mass_action indexing works.  If it was going to reindex the entire catalog then why would new data contain only the ids of the products I've updated?

Comment: In your case the index happens to the affected product. But the thing is if you are having simple product and configurable product relation then you are updating simple product on the bulk action and Magento try to index for their configurable products also.

This too based on the attributes of the product, if you are changing the status or url key of the product, then the URL reindex will be triggered.